# I have had an idea

Tags: verbs

1. *I've **had** this idea **for some time now**.*

I think we'd never say: *I've been **having** this idea for some time now.* (Present perfect continuous *with duration*). Instead we'd use the present perfect tense, as we've done in (1). Here, the main verb "have(**had**)" indicates **a state up to the present**.

2. *I’ve **had** an idea. Why don’t we walk into town?*

Once again, a present perfect use, but without a duration. we'd use it to mean the idea has come into our mind only recently. Here, the main verb "have(**had**) doesn't seem to indicate a state up to the present, but rather **an action/event** that has taken place in the recent past.

3. *I **have** an idea. Let's go to the cinema.*

Q: a) Does the main verb "have" have different meanings in 1), 2) and 3)?

b) Does the verb "have" in sentence (3) indicate a state or an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect continuous (even though it is, grammatically, the continuous form) refers to a series of interrupted occurrences. If you have had the same idea more or less constantly in an unaltered form in your mind for a period of time you use the simple past tense "I have had this idea for some time". If, however, you have had multiple ideas on the same theme you use the present continuous "I have been having these ideas for some time now".

A clearer example, perhaps, is the pair of sentences:

> "I have had this migraine for 24 hours now."

(the migraine stared 24 hours ago and has never gone away)

as opposed to

> "I have been having migraines since I was a teenager."

(not the same migraine in all that time, obviously, but suffering from the condition for years).

Comment: In your "migraine" examples, the main verbs "**had**" and "**having**" both mean **to suffer**. Am I right?

Comment: @Mr.X Not quite, it means that your body has the condition. In the case of migraines that means you suffer because of the pain but many people with medical conditions that don't cause pain (like epilepsy) will insist that they 'have' the condition but don't 'suffer from' it. Also if I used 'to suffer from' instead of 'to have' in my examples the tenses would be the same. That is I'd say 'have suffered from' and 'been suffering from'.

Comment: So it is some kind of an **"abstract" possession** of a disease, right?

Comment: It's not 'abstract' because you do have the condition and, in many cases it can be treated or even cured. It's just that you can 'have' some conditions or diseases without them actually making you 'suffer' in any real sense. In order to 'suffer from' a condition you have to 'have' it but 'having' a condition does not, necessarily mean that you have painful or frightening symptoms. If you  are asymptopic you might never know that you 'have' the condition at all, or certainly not until it starts to cause you problems when you start to 'suffer' from it.